# Attempting to sum the second column of a CSV file but receiving an error. How can I correct without the use of pandas?

Tags: python, csv

I have tried the following code:

This code works:

```
import csv

#create workable file
FILENAME = "monthly_sales.csv"

#Create View Monthly Sales Modual

sales = [] #sales will be the list name
with open(FILENAME, newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        sales.append(row)

sales_list = [int(row[1]) for row in sales]
sales_list_for_sum = [int(i) for i in sales_list] 
print(sales_list)
yearly_total = round(sum(sales_list),2)
list_length = len(sales_list)
monthly_average = round(yearly_total/list_length, 2)
print("Yearly Total: " + str(yearly_total))
print("Monthly Average: " + str(monthly_average))
```

But when i try to use this function in my code, i get the following error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'

```
def yearly_summary(sales):
    sales_list = [int(row[1]) for row in sales]
    print(sales_list)
    yearly_total = round(sum(sales_list),2)
    list_length = len(sales_list)
    monthly_average = round(yearly_total/list_length, 2)
    print("Yearly Total: " + str(yearly_total))
    print("Monthly Average: " + str(monthly_average))
```

I confirmed that there is no string 'e' in column two of the CSV file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: does your csv have headers? If so then `row[1]` is pulling the 2nd letter in the header which is an `e` and can't convert that to an into to an `int` because you aren't skipping the first row when you loop through the file. Would also help if you post the full stack trace for the error

Comment: It would make sense temporarily wrap the int(row[1]) conversion into try / except block for debugging purpose and log the invalid value. After locating it you would know whether it is a header issue or something else.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your literals are numeric rather than characters. Then, try converting your literal to float first and to int after that. So, use int(float()) wherever you have int(). Sometimes converting directly from string with several digits of fractional values to int cannot be done.

Comment: I have tried to int(float()) with no success. I also tried reader = csv.reader(file) with no success.

Comment: I have tried to int(float()) with no success. I also tried reader = csv.reader(file) with no success.

Traceback (most recent call last):

line 62, in <module>
    main()
line 60, in main
    yearly_summary(sales)
line 44, in yearly_summary
    sales_list = [int(row[1]) for row in sales]
line 44, in <listcomp>
    sales_list = [int(row[1]) for row in sales]

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e'

Answer (score 0):

I'm in agreement with Matthew Barlowe. Its my guess that you are reading in the header. Without more information it is hard to know. Would be helpful if you had the full traceback to indicate which line it is happening in (my guess is the list comprehension). You could try to see if adding a next to the reader would skip over your header.

```
next(reader)
```

Put that in right after

```
reader = csv.reader(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Below is the working code:

```
def yearly_summary(sales):
    with open ("monthly_sales.csv", "r") as file:
        sales = csv.reader(file)        
        sales_list = [int(row[1]) for row in sales]
        yearly_total = round(sum(sales_list),2)
        list_length = len(sales_list)
        monthly_average = round(yearly_total/list_length, 2)
        print("Yearly Total: " + str(yearly_total))
        print("Monthly Average: " + str(monthly_average))
```